# Directive To Directive communication and call to a passed function

Tags: angularjs

I have two directives and one controller which has a function test. My date directive has a button and on click is calling a function in the filter directive, which needs to call the function passed with entering, I tried doing `$scope.$apply($attrs.entering);` but I get `$apply already in progress`.

in HTML I have:

```
<filter entering="ctrl.test()">
  <date></date>
</filter>

app.directive('filter', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      this.sayHello = function() {
        // call function here $scope.$apply($attrs.entering);
      }
    }
  }
}
app.firective('date', function() {
  return {
    require: '^filter',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, filterCtrl) {
      scope.isClicked = function() {
        filterCtrl.say()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use $scope.$apply within angular controllers since they are already wrapped up in $scope.$apply implicitly. You may use $scope.$watch or $broadcast/$emit/$on depending on scenario.

Additional information: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html